# Accordion menu switch plus/minus does not work properly

Tags: jquery, accordion

Please help me to solve the problem with the switch plus / minus for multilevel accordion menu.
I can not understand how to make the plus and minus correctly switches as here http://www.nextendweb.com/demo/accordionmenu/vehicles-bold/car.html

Wrote a fully working code, except switch http://jsfiddle.net/a525drwp/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-1</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="js_slider"><a href="#">Level-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // hide submenu (works well)
        $('.js_slider ul').hide();

        // accordion multilevel menu (works well)
        $('.js_slider > a').on('click', function(event){
            var jsPro = $(this).parent('li');
            if (jsPro.hasClass('js_open')) {
                jsPro.removeClass('js_open');
                jsPro.find('li').removeClass('js_open');
                jsPro.find('ul').slideUp();
            }
            else {
                jsPro.addClass('js_open');
                jsPro.children('ul').slideDown();
                jsPro.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
                jsPro.siblings('li').removeClass('js_open');
                jsPro.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('js_open');
                jsPro.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        // add font-awesome icon
        $('.js_slider').addClass("fa fa-plus");


        //switch plus / minus (does not work properly)
        $('.fa-plus').click(function() {
            $('.js_slider').removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
            $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus ");
        });



    });// and ready
```

**CSS**

```
li {list-style: none;display: block !important;padding: 5px 0;}
a {text-decoration: none;padding-left: 5px;}
```

**Please help me!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a525drwp/3/)

I am adding and removing **fa-plus** and **fa-minus** which is a lot easier :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide submenu (works well)
    $('.js_slider ul').hide();

    // accordion multilevel menu (works well)
    $('.js_slider > a').on('click', function(event){
        var jsPro = $(this).parent('li');
        if (jsPro.hasClass('fa-minus')) {
            jsPro.removeClass('fa-minus');
            jsPro.addClass('fa-plus');
            jsPro.children().find('li.fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
            jsPro.children().find('li').removeClass('fa-minus');
            jsPro.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            jsPro.addClass('fa-minus');
            jsPro.removeClass('fa-plus');
            jsPro.children('ul').slideDown();
            jsPro.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            jsPro.siblings('li.fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
            jsPro.siblings('li').removeClass('fa-minus');
            jsPro.siblings('li').find('li.fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
            jsPro.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('fa-minus');
            jsPro.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // add font-awesome icon
    $('.js_slider').addClass("fa fa-plus");
});// and ready
```

Comment: Everything is working correctly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Noticed the error. If you open a sub menu, it does not continue to close, and close the parent. After reopen the parent, then the sub stays closed with a minus. A right to be should be open and the plus.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you want, you can add a callback to the first slideUp so you don't see the icons changing.

Comment: I have found another bug which added a + icon to your level 3 li's. Fixed it in another edit :)

Comment: Excellent menu turned out!